Measuring statistical significance of comparison results of two models with an imperfect classifier
I have a classifier with 87% accuracy for determining which of the outputs from two text generation models is closer in style to another sample text that is from some target author.
Using this classifier, how many sample comparisons between outputs of two text generation models against a sample text do I need to get statistical significance for showing that one generation model is better than another generation model in generating text in the style of the target author? The results are binary, where A > B or A < B for each comparison.
For a concrete example, one result using this classifier shows that A is better than B 60% of the time for 50 comparisons. At what significance level can we say that model A is better than model B?
I've asked this to ChatGPT (GPT-4) and Perplexity AI Pro, but all the answers I get are inconsistent and I don't know what to trust. They either suggest a one sample proportion test or a binomial test. I think the answer may be pretty straightforward when we assume the classifier is 100% correct, but not sure how to account for an imperfect classifier.

Check out McNemar test.
